# Is the output different because of the closure

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

```js
function test(str) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(str);
  }, 10000);
}

let i = "1";
test(i); //test 1
console.log(i, "sync");

i = "2";
test(i); //test 2
console.log(i, "sync");
```

Is it because of the closure that test 1 and 2 print 1 and 2 in sequence?
If I don't write setTimeout inside the function, the result is the last i value

Comment: `console.log`'ing in or outside of the `setTimeout` would be the same, as the value passed to `test` is copied so changing the original variable `i` wouldn't affect it

Comment: Is it because of closure?

Comment: `1` and `2` are logged in sequence because you first pass `1`, as a parameter, to the first `test` function call and `2` to the second function call. Callback function of `setTimeout` has a closure over the `str` parameter BUT the order of the output is not because of closure.

Comment: thank you so much for clarifying @Yousaf